# Use Taylor polynomials with remainder term to evaluate the following limits $\large\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

My work:

Since $\large e^x=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}$, then $\large\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}=\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty \frac{x^{j-2}}{j!}=\sum\limits_{d=0}^\infty \frac{x^{d}}{(d+2)!}$. (Let d=j-2)

My question:

Infinite series is of the form $\large\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j(x-a)^j$.

(1) If I am  changing the series into the form above, does $\large a_j=\frac{1^j}{(j+2)!}$?

(2) If (1) is correct, is $"\large R=\lim_{j\to\infty}|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}|=\lim_{j\to\infty}|\frac{1}{j+3}|=0"$ correct?

Does it comes to the conclusion that this series converges for any real number x?

Comment: You've conflated $n$ and $j$, but, yes, the series converges for any real (or even complex) $x$. Note that removing a finite number of terms from a series or multiplying all terms by a nonzero constant ($1/x^2$ in this case) does not affect its convergence.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: @nbubis I have updated the question, would you please take a look?

Comment: @CarlLove That's what I thought, I wonder if I am correct in the process :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
e^x-x-1 = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots
$$
Dividing that by $x^2$, you get
$$
\frac 1 2 + \frac x 6 + \frac{x^2}{24} + \cdots
$$

If you mean limit as $x\to0$, that should now become apparent.

(If you mean limit as $x\to\text{something else}$, then you need to clarify that.)